# Symfony multiple route requirements from constants

Tags: symfony, annotations, symfony-3.4

I'm working on a Symfony 3.4 project, and I need to add a requirement on my route like :

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}", defaults={"_locale"="en"}, requirements={
 *     "_locale"="en|fr"
 * })
 */
public function homepageAction($_locale)
{
    // ...
}
```

You can see `"_locale"="en|fr"`, my problem is I need to get `en` and `fr` from a constant class not directly in the annotation.

So something like `"_locale"="MY_FIRST_CONSTANTE|MY_SECOND_CONSTANTE"`

I'm struggling with the syntax.

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your class where your constants are stored:

```
const EN = 'en'
const FR = 'fr'

const REQUIREMENTS = self::EN.'|'.self::FR;
```

Then, in your controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}", defaults={"_locale"=App\Locales::EN}, requirements={
 *     "_locale"=App\Locales::REQUIREMENTS
 * })
 */
public function homepageAction($_locale)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It's for the requirement attribute with the "|"

Comment: Did you tried this ? I have an erro : Couldn't find constant AppBundle\UserRolesEnum::getRouteRequirementsForAdminToggle (it's the equivalent of App\Locales::getRouteRequirements( in my project)

Comment: Hmm so you can't call a function with annotations, edited my answer again, sorry.